# Add files/folders/Apps to a new User Account

Tags: google-chrome, file-transfer

I have created a new user account for my roommate. I/we don't really care much for IE, and I'd like to add Google Chrome, and FF for her, to let her choose her own browser. Plus I'd like to add some other apps for her, and transfer some of her personal info that she's been storing on my administrative acct. (i.e. personal photos and such). So, like I said the account is set up. But when I go to use Chrome, it won't open. It, along with other apps are listed in the list of "approved" applications under the parental control list. (Application Restrictions List) But they either don't show up when searched for,( in her acct.) or won't open and operate. One other example is Faststone Capture. And then, I've got one application, Yahoo, "Unchecked", and yet there it is in her account, AND IT WORKS! I do not get it. The purpose to setting up an account for her was to only restrict that she couldn't delete, or uninstall anything on the computer. I don't care, (obviously within reason) what she installs, but NO TAKING AWAY! Here is a screen shot of the restrictions list:

[image]

So, here I sit, wondering what I did wrong, or forgot to do in order for these to work. I don't care if Yahoo works or not. But her photos being transferred, Chrome/FF working, and Faststone Capture working, are a priority for me. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate any advice.

My account is an Administrative one. The account I am creating for her is just a Standard User Acct.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it looks like some of the things you have selected are installers.  As a non-admin account she won't be able to install so that is a bit fruitless.

I also notice that Chrome is installed under your user "c:\Users\Odean" (i.e. you installed for your user only not for the whole system).  Apps will often ask if you want to install for just yourself or for everyone on the computer.  Since it is in your user folder, she will not have the proper file permissions to open the file even if parental controls allow her to use them.  Is there any reason to restrict what apps she is using anyway?  From your description it looks like parental controls are off base from what you want.

I think you may need to just reinstall the things that aren't working and make sure your choose to enable access to everyone on the machine.

P.S. OS would likely be helpful in future posts.  Is that Vista, Windows 7?  This can be pretty helpful to those who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Chrome is installed only for current user, not for all users of a machine. So enter her account, open a installer of Google Chrome, give your admin password if it requires test Google Chrome.

I don't know what is FS Capture, but it is installed in your user account. Use the same procedure to install it (if you have the installer).

Do not forget:

- to verify if all common program shortcuts in Start Menu and Desktop are working. Perhaps you would have more programs installed only for your user. Enter her user account and try them
- to verify if all shortcuts are available to her account. Some of them could be only on your user Start Menu, not in All Users Start Menu. If so, copy or move them from your user Start Menu to All Users Start Menu (in Windows 7, from "c:\users\your user\start menu" to "c:\users\all users\start menu" / in Windows XP, from "c:\documents and settings\your user\start menu" to "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu"). Then, enter her user account and try them

Note: In Windows 7, if there is no option to give admin password when installing something, hold shift and right click on a program to choose "Run as administrator"